# Is there a way to implement function from useMemo into useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following a tutorial on sorting an table.

Now at last part I've noticed that in the tutorial, person was using `useMemo` where I don't use it at all. Now problem is that I cannot change my code because of this feature, so I'm asking you guys is something that I do to get sorting working??

I think my first problem is that I'm using one object who has key:value pairs and where values are arrays, and in tutorial response is arrays of objects. When I try to sort my arrays I get error `dataArr[0].map is not a function` and this function works in the render. Also I get `console.log` of undefined when trying to `console.log(arr)` inside of `useMemo` but if i use it outside, i get normal log of data.

Also I'm recently started learning ReactJS and I never came across `useMemo`.

[Link to github of the tutorial](https://github.com/codegeous/react-component-depot/blob/master/src/pages/DataTable/index.js)

My component where I implemented this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from 'react-validation/build/form';
import Input from 'react-validation/build/input';
import CheckButton from 'react-validation/build/button';

import TableHeader from './TableHeader';
import ArticleService from '../services/article.service';

const Article = (props) => {
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState([]);
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({ field: '', order: '' });

  const headers = [
    { name: 'Informacije o banci', field: 'bankname', sortable: false },
    { name: 'NKS', field: 'nks', sortable: true },
    { name: 'Ukupna cijena', field: 'price', sortable: true },
    { name: 'Mjesečna rata', field: 'rate', sortable: true },
  ];

  const [months, setMonths] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onChangeMonths = (e) => {
    const months = e.target.value;
    setMonths(months);
  };

  const handleMonths = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setLoading(true);

    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      try {
        const res = await ArticleService.article(id, months);
        setContent(res.data);
        const data = res.data.kredit;
        const dataArr = [];
        dataArr.push({
          name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
          price: data.kreditNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
          rate: data.rataNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
          nks: data.stopaNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          eks: data.stopaEKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          bankname: data.ime.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          type: data.tip.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
        });
        setDataArr(dataArr);

        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const res = await ArticleService.article(id);
      setContent(res.data);
      const data = res.data.kredit;
      const dataArr = [];
      dataArr.push({
        name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
        price: data.kreditNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        rate: data.rataNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        nks: data.stopaNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),

        eks: data.stopaEKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),

        bankname: data.ime.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),

        type: data.tip.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
      });
      setDataArr(dataArr);
    };
    fetchPosts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const data = useMemo(() => {
    const arr = dataArr;
    console.log(arr);
    if (sorting.field) {         <--------- This part i need to implement somewhere in the code
      const reversed = sorting.order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
      return (
        dataArr[0] &&
        dataArr[0].map((item) =>
          item.nks.sort(
            (a, b) =>
              reversed * a[sorting.field].localeCompare(b[sorting.field])
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }, [sorting]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className='text-dark'>
        <Link to='/dashboard'>
          <i className='fas fa-arrow-left'></i> Nazad
        </Link>
      </p>
      <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
        <strong>Artikal id:{content.id}</strong>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Opis:
            <br></br>
            {content.descr}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena
            <br></br>
            {content.price}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena po metru kvadratnom:
            <br></br>
            {content.ppm2}/m2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        <h3>KREDITI ZA CIJENU {content.price}</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={handleMonths} ref={form}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Vrijeme otplate u mjesecima:</label>
            <Input
              type='text'
              className='form-control w-25'
              name='months'
              value={months}
              onChange={onChangeMonths}
            />

            <button
              className='btn btn-primary btn-block w-25'
              disabled={loading}
            >
              {loading && (
                <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm'></span>
              )}
              <span>Prikaži</span>
            </button>
            <CheckButton style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={checkBtn} />

            <small>
              Ako se ne unese vrijeme otplate kredita, kredit se izračunava za
              60 mjeseci
            </small>
            <br></br>
            <Input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Unos max. kamatne stope'
              value={value}
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>

      <table className='table text-center'>
        <TableHeader
          headers={headers}
          onSorting={(field, order) => setSorting({ field, order })}
        />
        <tbody>
          {dataArr[0] &&
            dataArr[0].nks
              .filter((item) => {
                if (!value) {
                  return item;
                } else {
                  return item < value;
                }
              })
              .map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td className='d-flex flex-column align-items-center'>
                    <h4>{dataArr[0].bankname[i]}</h4>
                    <span>EKS: {dataArr[0].eks[i]}</span>
                    <span>Tip: {dataArr[0].type[i]}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td className='align-middle'>
                    <h4>{item}</h4>
                  </td>
                  <td className='align-middle'>
                    <h4>{dataArr[0].price[i]} KM</h4>
                  </td>
                  <td className='align-middle'>
                    <h4>{dataArr[0].rate[i]} KM/mj</h4>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

Note that clicking on header in the table, `onClick` is triggered I just get an error and to be honest, I have no idea how to fix this.

Also if u have some tutorial of sorting that would be easy to implement into my project I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is `console.log(dataArr[0])` and `console.log(arr)` note that `arr` one is undefiend.
[image: console log]

Comment: Can you add `dataArr` in the dependency array of `useMemo`? And instead of iterating through `dataArr` can you iterate through `data`?

Comment: `data` is basically same sa `dataArr` just I've formated it to easier map it when creating the table. I'm sorry but I don't know anything about dependency arrays :(. How I would do that?

Comment: `data` is same as `dataArr` but the question is why you need the `useMemo`? Because you want to store the data in memory.
Dependency array is the second parameter of the `useMemo` function. You already have  that like: `[sorting]`. Just change it to `[sorting, dataArr]`

Comment: I would suggest you read the official doc of `useMemo` hook and you will get a better idea about when should you use the `useMemo` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: I was following this tutorial, I never used it before, so I've tried it implementing to get working my sorting. Do u have some example that i can use sorting with my project?

Comment: Can you put your code in Github. I could look into your code

Comment: [link to github](https://github.com/emsoaldin/ReactAppRepo/tree/master) U can also run it on your local device because backend routes are on Azure services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227967/discussion-between-shuvo-and-aldinho).